# Copy markdown formatted tables from SO to pandas clipboard

Tags: python, pandas

I am comfortable in using `pd.read_clipboard()` when the data posted on SO has spaces between columns (`'\s\s+'`)

However, how would one copy the below table directly to a pandas dataframe?

| Record ID | Shared On (UNIX timestamp) | Share type | Share To User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1611872850 | shared | user A |
| 2 | 1611872851 | shared | user B |
| 3 | 1611872852 | shared | user B |
| 1 | 1611872853 | share_removed | user A |

I tried finding something that would help me with this and the closest I got to copying this dataframe was using the following which has a lot of unnecessary columns and unnecessary spaces that I have to later use `df.col.str.strip()` to clean up.

```
#Clicking edit on the question, and copying the underlying markdown
pd.read_clipboard('|')
```

```
   Unnamed: 0   Record ID    Shared On<br/>(UNIX timestamp)    \
0         NaN  ------------                      ------------   
1         NaN   1                                 1611872850    
2         NaN   2                                 1611872851    
3         NaN   3                                 1611872852    
4         NaN   1                                 1611872853    

    Share type       Share To User   Unnamed: 5  
0  ---------------  ---------------         NaN  
1   shared           user A                 NaN  
2   shared           user B                 NaN  
3   shared           user B                 NaN  
4   share_removed    user A                 NaN
```

Anyone know of a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like

```
pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s*\|\s*').iloc[1:,1:-1]
```

works pretty well. Output:

```
  Record ID Shared On<br/>(UNIX timestamp)     Share type Share To User
1         1                     1611872850         shared        user A
2         2                     1611872851         shared        user B
3         3                     1611872852         shared        user B
4         1                     1611872853  share_removed        user A
```

Comment: Thanks! I assumed it would be somewhat like this. Was hoping for something inbuilt or a library/API that is made to handle this specifically. Upvoting for now and will mark after waiting for some time incase some other solution comes up.

Comment: +1, but I also think it should be noted that this works if you can edit the question and copy the markdown, but it doesn't work to just copy the rendered table in the question.